# Notice: Undefined offset: 4 while opening website

Tags: magento-1.7, error

Today When I run my store it says following error message..

> Notice: Undefined offset: 4  in /var/www/vhosts/myhost.com/Myproject/app/design/frontend/tapestore/default/template/catalog/product/featured_list.phtml on line 171

The following code is found in that place...

```
166 <?php if ($desct) { ?>
167     <div class="product-grid-description">
168        <ul>
169        <?php
170             $i = 0;
171             while ($desctexpl[$i] && $i < 4) {
172                   echo "<li>" . Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate($desctexpl[$i], '40') . "</li>";
173                   $i++;
174             }
175         ?>
176         </ul>
177     </div>
178 <?php } ?>
```

Could any one suggest what might be the problem ? and how to solve it ?

Comment: Please share all code of featured_list.phtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code:

```
166 <?php if ($desct) { ?>
167     <div class="product-grid-description">
168        <ul>
169        <?php
170             $i = 0;                   
171               while (array_key_exists($i,$desctexpl) && $i < 4) {
172                   echo "<li>" . Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate($desctexpl[$i], '40') . "</li>";
173                   $i++;
174               }                   
175         ?>
176         </ul>
177     </div>
178 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: it worked fine @PrashantValanda. Can I ask why did this happen ? Because it was working before .

Comment: May be there is no value for $desctexpl[$i] where $i = 4. So it will trigger notice.